# The option to "Administer Test Controllers" is not available on the Test menu in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC Version 11.0.50522.1 RCREL onto Windows 8 RP on a Virtual Machine running Hyper-V on Server 2012 RC DataCenter.

All the documentation states that if you want to administer the Test Controllers in a Load test rig, you have to click on "Administer Test Controllers" in the "Test" menu. However, I don't have that option in the Test menu. I've tried adding it manually, but then it simply remains unavailable.[image]

What am I doing wrong? This is really holding me back.

I am able to administer test controllers by creating a dummy load test and then right-Clicking on the "Controller Machine" Note and selecting "Manage Test Controllers" from there. The issue I have is that I think there might be some other menu items missing: How do you set the active Controller (I have 4 set-up). It seems to try to run the tests locally, but then the TestResults databases I have created for each of the 4 controllers aren't used, and it can't find it.

**Edit:**
I've submitted a bug with Microsoft at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758768/can-not-administer-or-manage-test-controllers-from-the-test-menu

Comment: I was able to resolve this by installing the final versions. You have to also have a WebAndLoadTestProject project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on a load test.

[image]

It is also available in the menu item "LOAD TEST".

Answer (score 3):

As Cybermaxs said, you can find the "Manage Test Controllers" command in the **Load Test** menu. However, this menu is only visible if you have a C# Web Performance and Load Test project in your solution. It doesn't help you if you only have standard C# MS Test projects.

The good new is, you can manually add the "Manage Test Controllers" option to your **Test** menu, which is always visible.

**Workaround:**
Notice that I have a Unit Test project in my solution, but no Web Performance and Load Test projects.

[image]

I have a **Test** menu, but no **Load Test** menu.

[image]

My **Test** Menu does not contain the *Manage Test Controllers* option

[image]

**To manually add the command:**

- Right-click anywhere in that menu bar area and select "Customize".

[image]

- In the *Commands* tab, select the **Test** menu bar from the drop down.
- Click the *Add Command* button, scroll down and select the **Load Test** category, and what do you know... there it is. The "Manager Test Controllers" command.

[image]

- Select it and click "OK" to add it to the menu. Use "Move Up" and "Move Down" to position it to you liking (personally, I prefer it just above the first break).
- Click "Close" to save, and with a feeling of success, see that the prodigal command has returned :)

[image]